# ViewModel vs. Domain Model field differences

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was using Entity Framework designer with ASP.Net Web Pages few days ago. I'm switching code first and MVC application now. I already have the model code (created by VS model designer) so i'm using those. They have already relation (navigation) codes like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserUsername { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public decimal UserType { get; set; }
    public decimal BranchId { get; set; }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is a relation between **Users** and **Branches**. It's working right now but after switching MVC i learned that i need to use ViewModels and not the models i created first, here is the problem, i will definitely include **public virtual Branch Branch** to my ViewModel but should i keep that line in my original model (domain model)? Because i won't use **Branch** while saving, i will only need BranchId.

I'm so confused and doing things takes much more time with MVC for me (for now).

Thanks

Comment: YEs you still need that, your viewmodel is gonna be whatever fields you want.... your domain model needs the virtual so it knows the relationship

Comment: Your view model should not contain `public virtual Branch Branch` unless you also editing all properties of `Branch` (which you have indicated you don't) but your data model must. Best guess is that you want a dropdownlist to select a branch for a User, in which case your view model should also contain a `SelectList` for Branches